# How can I access checkbox view in a RecyclerView Adapter class from a layout file?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

```
class TodoAdapter (var todos:List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

inner class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {

    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.todo_layout, parent, false)
    return TodoViewHolder(view)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.apply {
    }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return todos.size
}
```

}

Here is the adapter class.

[Link to layout xml file for adapter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5vxC.png)

What I want is to access the checkbox and textview from xml file inside

```
holder.itemView.apply{
tvTask.text = todos[position].title
cbTask.isChecked = todos[position].isChecked
}
```

title and isChecked are variables declared in a data class of string and boolean type respectively

My inner class contains itemViews since I am trying to make a To-Do app. So it returns items to the constructor.

Comment: What is your exact problem as your code seems to be fine.?

Comment: Well we cannot access textview and checkboxes and other views using kotlin synthetics since it is deprecated.

Comment: If it was something in the MainActivity.kt, I would have used ViewBinding and accessed the views/buttons/checkboxes.

Comment: The line should be something like:
holder.itemView.apply
{
  binding.tvTask.text = todos[position].title
  binding.cbTask.isChecked = todos[position].isChecked
}

But this isn't working because I do not know how to use ViewBinding in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

To enable ViewBinding, add the following piece of code to the app-level build.gradle file.

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

XML file is wrapped with `layout` tag and that seems to be fine.

And now refactor the ViewHolder class's constructor to take a `binding` variable.

```
inner class TodoViewHolder(val binding: TodoLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

note: `inner` modifier is optional here.

The `binding` variable can be accessed in the `onBindViewHolder` method's `holder` variable.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.binding.apply {
    // ...access the views here...
    }

}
```